# Can I plot pandas.DataFrame and normal line from function or array in the same subplot?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I have a pandas `DataFrame` that is stacked and reorganized as I wish and looks like this:

```
print(df.unstack(level=0).cumsum())
Task           1020     1021     1022      1023     7141
Entry Date                                              
2019-03-31      NaN      NaN      NaN   32930.0      NaN
2019-04-30  28845.0  16695.0  27427.5  127476.0      NaN
2019-05-31  57465.0  85745.0      NaN  142561.0  3515.61
2019-06-30      NaN  90515.0      NaN       NaN      NaN
```

This I plot with the following lines:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1)
grouped_by_task.unstack(level=0).cumsum().plot(ax=ax1, style = '.-')
```

Now, I want to add another graph (for the case of simplicity a straight line between two points).

These endpoints of this line is given by:

```py
startmonth = '2019-03'
endmonth = '2022-03'
start_month = datetime.strptime(startmonth, "%Y-%m")
end_month = datetime.strptime(endmonth, "%Y-%m")
budget = [0, 1000000]
times = [start_month, end_month]
```

I am struggling with getting the line subplot on the same plot.

I have found several discussions on how to add data from several `DataFrame`s in the same subplot, but not a pandas `DataFrame` together with values not in a `DataFrame`.

I try plotting with the following lines:

```py
grouped_by_task.unstack(level=0).cumsum().plot(ax=ax1, style = '.-') # (1)
ax1.plot(times, budget, '-')                                         # (2)
plt.xlim(datetime.strptime(startmonth, "%Y-%m"), 
         datetime.strptime(endmonth, "%Y-%m")                        # (3)
```

With only line (1) I get a plot where both x and y axis are determined by the data in the `DataFrame`.

[image: Only DataFrame]

With line (3) as well the x-axis is determined correctly (longer than the data available in the `DataFrame`).

[image: DataFrame plotted with x-axis redefined]

With all 3 lines I get the y-axis adjusted to values according to the data in line (2), but without the line.

[image: Y-axis readjusted according to line, but line not plotted]

If I comment out line (1) I get the line plotted correctly.

[image: Line shows up when DataFrame not plotted]

The only difference is that the values at the tics of the x-axis are written differently.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your data as much as possible. Your example is not fully reproducible as it is. Anyway, changing the order in which to plot the line, set limits and plot the DataFrame solved it for me. The DataFrame has to go last. Sorry, no idea why...
The data I used:

```
Task           1020     1021     1022      1023     7141
2019-03-31      NaN      NaN      NaN   32930.0      NaN
2019-04-30  28845.0  16695.0  27427.5  127476.0      NaN
2019-05-31  57465.0  85745.0      NaN  142561.0  3515.61
2019-06-30      NaN  90515.0      NaN       NaN      NaN
```

Parsing the data:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+')
df['Task'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Task'])
df = df.set_index('Task')
start_month = datetime.strptime('2019-03', "%Y-%m")
end_month = datetime.strptime('2022-03', "%Y-%m")
budget = [0, 1000000]
```

And the plotting part. Note that the df goes last:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot([start_month, end_month], budget, '-', label='budget')
df.groupby(df.index).cumsum().plot(ax=ax1, style='.-', xlim=(start_month, end_month))
ax1.legend()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked. If anyone knows the reason it could be useful information to add. Changing the order of the plots worked perfectly. Sorry about the data not being reproducible. I will do better next time.